# NetBeans:JasperReport Exception

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I'm working on a project that needs Jasper reporting, I have used the code fragment mentioned below to view the report in NetBeans 6.1 (the report is originally generated and compiled using iReport 3.6.0),my requirement is to print this report using a simple Swing application.

Code fragment:

```
    public class JasperCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reportSource = "E:/Projects/report.jrxml";
        String reportDest = "E:/Projects/report.html";

        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {

            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);

            JasperPrint jasperPrint =
                    JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);

            JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint);
        } catch (JRException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run this it gives an exception that I couldn't figure out.

```
Exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:157)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:115)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.getCompiler(JasperCompileManager.java:511)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:215)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:148)
        at src.JasperCheck.main(JasperCheck.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationFailedException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
        ... 8 more
Java Result: 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jasperPrint, reportDest);
```

See [`JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile()`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperExportManager.html#exportReportToHtmlFile(net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint,%20java.lang.String)). I assume that's the method you mean.

Comment: It can't possibly give the same exception. Your exception is because you're passing a HTML filename as the source file and Jasper can't read it. The method I'm suggesting passes **jasperPrint**, which is not an HTML file so it'll either work or throw a different exception.

Comment: I have figured it out the problem cause because of a missing jar file

Comment: i am getting the same problem can you please tell me which jar was missing?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9063533/51280) further down the page, unfortunately not marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

It means that the [***`groovy`***](http://groovy.codehaus.org) library dependency is missing.

We can add the `groovy-1.7.5.jar` (it depends on `JasperReports` version) in classpath to resolve this issue.

We can find the ***`groovy`***'s dependency in the the `JasperReports` library `pom.xml` file. For the JR 4.5.0 version it is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

In case of using **`maven`** we can add this dependency to the project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because, while creating a report you have selected language as Grrovy but this using jrxml in java program.In jrxml file,

Comment: How can i change it to java?