# Extracting jasper reports with java issue: NoClassDefFound Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jasper-reports

Tried integrating java code with Jasper and facing the below mentioned issue in console.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
```

can anyone help for the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetBeans:JasperReport Exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576532/netbeansjasperreport-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the correct host language in your report? It should be Java, and you might have accidentially set it to Groovy, or might have forgotten to change it to Java. Check the properties view:

[image].

Hope that helps!
Best regards, h.

Comment: Why it should be *Java*? It can be *Groovy* and in this case the *Groovy* lib should be added to classpath

Comment: Well.. he stated that he had issues integrating it with a Java project, it's right there, the third word in his question. Hence, the assumption that he tries to integrate it with Java, not Groovy. I would have expected a mention of Groovy in the brief question itself.